# Is it possible to reference APIs of the collection in the collection documentation?

Tags: postman

Postman allows to create documentation on API as well as Collection level.

While it allows to add hyperlinks etc does it also allow to add a clickable reference to one of the APIs that I have in the collection?

[image]

Comment: If you hover over an elements title, while in a tab, it will give you a shared link which can be added to the docs. Currently, that link will open the Web version of Postman at that particular point though.

Comment: @DannyDainton I wonder why they could not open it within the desktop app itself. But this will do for me for now. Thank you so much.

Comment: It's just not currently an option within the app at the moment, deep linking to entities in the desktop version will come though.